# SmartTarget - Additional Help Content on Trigger selection

Tags: smarttarget, gui-extensions

Is there any way of adding additional help content into the UI when a user selects a trigger, this is to guide them in their selection of triggers that may also rely/be-required based on their selection. For informational purposes only (not "intelligent")

[image: Somethign like this:]

Would this have to be a GUI Extension? (please also elaborate if possible on where/how - as SmartTarget example extensions are not readily available online as far as I see)

Thanks!
Brad